# Can't get even a simple uwsgi test to work

Tags: python, uwsgi

I'm trying to get nginx/django/uwsgi set up, and I'm stuck at the first step. I'm just trying to get uwsgi to serve a test application directly to my browser, as described here as a [basic test](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html).

So, I create the test.py file:

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"]
```

And then I start it up with `$ uwsgi --plugins python --http :8001 --wsgi-file test.py`

The output appears to be OK. I get the message `WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x3a14c8 pid: 8295 (default app).` I would expect that I would then be able to aim my browser at 127.0.0.1:8001, and see a hello world message. However, chrome just tells me that the site can't be reached.

I've been trying various permutations of tests from all over the internet for a solid day, but this is the simplest test I've found, and no one mentions what to do if it fails.

For reference, I'm using uwsgi 2.0.15 and python 3.6.1 on Arch.

**EDIT:** Evidently someone thought my question "did not show any research effort." So, to summarize what I've tried:

- I checked that iptables wasn't blocking anything
- I tried it on various ports
- I tried moving on with the tutorial to see if it works with a real django project
- I tried doing this all in a virtualenv
- I tried running from a uwsgi ini file instead of the command line
- I tried starting over any using various other tutorials.
- Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068100/super-basic-uwsgi-configuration?rq=1) and tried the answer

Output of `$ curl -v 127.0.0.1:8001`:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1:8001/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8001 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8001: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8001: Connection refused
```

Please let me know if you can think of anything else.

Comment: "works for me". uwsgi 2.0.15, python 3.5.3, ubuntu, chromium

Comment: Using Chrome means you have a lot more potentially involved (browser plugins, proxy config, etc). I'd strongly suggest starting somewhere more barebones -- ie. with `curl -v`. That'll also give you an exact error message you can include in the question, which will go a long way towards giving us *something* we can work with.

Comment: Are you sure the process is alive after the start? What does `ps aux` say about it? What does `netstat -f inet` say about port 8001?

Comment: Yep. `ps aux | grep uwsgi` shows the process is alive (actually, processes... I'm not trying emperor mode yet). `netstat -f inet` returns an error related to the AF BLUETOOTH feature, and I haven't figured out what's up with that yet. It's worth noting that I **can** access the default page served by nginx, so at least some network operations work, but nothing at the uwsgi level.